# Python selecting different number of rows for each group of a mutlilevel index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with a multilevel index. I would like to sort this data frame based on a specific column and extract the first n rows for each group of the first index, but n is different for each group.
For example:

```
| Index1| Index2| Sort_In_descending_order |  How_manyRows_toChoose   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |  20   |           3              |            2             |
|       |  40   |           2              |            2             |
|       |  10   |           1              |            2             |
|   2   |  20   |           2              |            1             |
|       |  50   |           1              |            1             |
```

the result should look like this:

```
| Index1| Index2| Sort_In_descending_order |  How_manyRows_toChoose   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |  20   |           3              |            2             |
|       |  40   |           2              |            2             |
|   2   |  20   |           2              |            1             |
```

I got this far:
`df.groupby(level[0,1]).sum().sort_values(['Index1','Sort_In_descending_order'],ascending=False).groupby('Index1').head(2)` 
However the `.head(2)` picks 2 element of each group independent of the number in the column "How_manyRows_toChoose".

Some pice of code would be great!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `head` and add parameter `group_keys=False` for avoid duplicated index values:

```
#original code
df = (df.groupby(level[0,1])
        .sum()
        .sort_values(['Index1','Sort_In_descending_order'],ascending=False))

df = (df.groupby('Index1', group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda x: x.head(x['How_manyRows_toChoose'].iat[0])))
print (df)
               Sort_In_descending_order  How_manyRows_toChoose
Index1 Index2                                                 
1      20                             3                      2
       40                             2                      2
2      20                             2                      1
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks! To make sure, the values in the column "Sort_In_descending_order" are sorted I do `df=df.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum().sort_values(['Index1', 'Sort_In_descending_order '], ascending=False)` before your pice of code.